# How is calling base() for a class different from inheritnece

Tags: c#, inheritance

I think I might be getting C++ mixed up with C# but I don't understand why in this C# code they;re calling the super class base(). Isn't everything already inherited?

```
    class Animal
    {
      public double height{get;set;}

      public Animal()
      {
        this.height=0;
      }

    class Dog:Animal
    {
      public string favFood{get;set;}

      public Dog():base() //Why not just omit the base? Doesn't dog inherit already from Animal?
      {
        this.favFood="No favorite food";
      }
    }
   }
```

Comment: You're right. There's no need to call the base constructor there explicitly. However, if the `Animal` constructor required arguments to be passed in, you'd pass them in through a `base` call like that.

Comment: `base()` doesn't make it inherit something - it just chains to the base class constructor. In this case it isn't necessary, but if you chain to a constructor using arguments, you need to.

Comment: why don't you get rid of the call to `:base()` and see what happens?

Comment: Also no need for the couple of `this.`. So I'm assuming it's just to demonstrate what's actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

All constructors must call into the constructor of their base type. It's just that C# allows you to omit the call to `base()` as long as there's a default constructor in the base type. However, when your code is compiled, that call to the base constructor gets inserted there by default. (Remember that everything in C# is an object, so technically even `Animal` is calling into its base type's constructor, but without an explicit `base()` call it's always calling into `System.Object`'s default constructor.

The `base` keyword starts to come in handy when the base type has non-default constructors, as this allows you to determine which constructor to call.

```
class Animal
{
  private readonly string name;
  public double height{get;set;}

  public Animal(string name)
  {
    this.name = 0;
    this.height=0;
  }

class Dog:Animal
{
  public string favFood{get;set;}

  public Dog():base("Fido")
  {
    this.favFood="No favorite food";
  }
}
```

}

In the above example, `name` can only be set by the `Animal`'s constructor, so `Dog` has to send a value up to that constructor via the `base()` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the following. In this case `Animal` has a constructor with one parameter of type double. Since, `Dog` inherits `Animal` should supply this parameter to the base constructor

```
class Animal
{
    public double Height { get; set;}

    public Animal(double height)
    {
        Height = height;
    }
}

class Dog: Animal
{
    public string FavoriteFood { get; set; }

    public Dog(double height): base(height) 
    {
        FavoriteFood = "No favorite food";
    }
}
```

In your case, as already both itsme86 and Jon Skeet have mentioned, you don't have to use the `: base()`, since your base constructor is parameterless.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `base()` you are talking about is specifying which constructor of the base class to call, this way if you had two different constructors for the base you'd be able to choose which to execute :

```
class Animal
{
  public double Height{get;set;}
  public string Name {get; private set;}

  public Animal()
  {
    this.height=0;
  }

  protected Animal(string name)
  {
    Name=name;
  }
}

class Dog : Animal
{
   public string FavoriteFood{get;set;}

  //this calls the constructor with name parameter
  public Dog(string name):base(name)
  {
    this.FavoriteFood="No favorite food";
  }

  //this one calls the parameterless constructor
  //this is optional, if its not included then 
  //behaves the same as : base()
  protected Dog(int height):base()
  {
    this.favFood="No favorite food";
  }
}
```

This syntax can also be used to call other constructors from the same class which can be useful if you have a parameterized constructor and want a default set of parameters

```
//this construtor calls the current classes constructor taking a name 
protected Dog():this("Dog")
{

}
```

Comment: For your last example, I would rather have a constructor like `protected Dog(string name = "Dog")`, chaining inner constructors can get confusing pretty fast

Comment: @Dispersia I agree, but defaults need to be available at compile time, so the two are not equivalent

Comment: if they're calling the base constructor, there is no chance of being able to pass to an alternate constructor besides an already defined value anyway

Comment: @konkked if I were to code this in c++ how would the function know which constructor to call? I'm assuming its still based on the arguments given but we wouldn't have the key word base so thats making me a little confused

Comment: @I_love_coding_93 : C++ is rusty but think it would be something like `Dog(...):Animal(...)`

Comment: @Konkked So why doesn't C# do the same way as C++? I just don't understand why base is any different from using the term of the main class

Comment: @I_love_coding_93 I'm not sure why, but would guess it would have to do with the fact that since there is no multiple-inheritance the base class can be inferred, so why not just use the `base` keyword? But that is just my guess

Answer (score 0):

It's been *kind of* said, but along with the ability to pass parameters to base type constructors, this mechanism also allows selecting which of the constructor overloads to call on a base type.